# При service.AddMvc не может найти файл(assembly) проекта, притом еще и название обрезанное

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Вот скрин с ошибкой:
[image: Скрин с ошибкой]

VS 2017, ASP.NET Core, .NET Core 1.1
Запускаю проект miraArchive.Drive.WebService.
Внезапно, после копания в IIS Express настройках появилась эта ошибка.

Откатил ISS, откатил VS, кучу раз почистил, полазал в инете. Подобные проблемы только со с обычными библиотеками, привязанными. Привязанный похожий проект проверил связь(удалил, поставил заново). Все ок.

Скопировал 2 раза в новые папки из общего репозитория. У всех запускается, у меня нет.

Куда копать? Уже задолбался с этим возиться...

UPDATE: проверил еще на возможность обрезания пути(слишком длинный). Не прошло. 
Также запустил новый проект. Она срабатывает. Проблема походу в настройках проекта...Но у других работает.

Comment: Возможно у библиотеки которую вы собираетесь подключить версия .Net Framework выше чем у проекта который вы собираете. Проверьте

Comment: @V.Dmitriy это не библиотека. Это и есть название проекта

Comment: В этом случае проверьте версию .net framework у проекта который вы подключаете, если вопрос ещё актуален. Если не актуален, то расскажите в чем была проблема.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy отписал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге выяснилось, что проблема была в компе(скорее всего в настройках).

Возможно в том, что у меня Intel Nuc. Перепробовал кучу вариантов. Переустановка системы помогла.